# CORS settings in router.get() Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I have a white list of URLs

I have trouble using it with GET requests, but with POST it works.

For POST everything works.

For GET I took an example from the Express website. It doesn't work. Cors allowed GET requests from any domain.

```js
const allowedList =["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3001"]

const corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (allowedList.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    }
}

const corsOptionsGet = function (req, callback) {
    let corsOptions;
    if (allowedList.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
        corsOptions = { origin: true }
    } else {
        corsOptions = { origin: false }
    }
    callback(null, corsOptions)
}

router.post("/add-item", cors(corsOptions), addItem);
router.get("/get-item", cors(corsOptionsGet), getItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling your server? if you are using tools like `Postman` or `curl` the Origin header is not set by default and you need to manually add it to the request header.

Comment: I call the server from http://localhost:3005 and I get a response ok.  http://localhost:3005 isn't in white list, so I expect an error

Comment: That's a misunderstanding of how CORS works: the request shouldn't fail but instead, the response includes an appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header that the browser can use to determine whether to grant access to the client based on its origin.

So you should check that your Express server response headers include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with appropriate value and not expect for the server to fail

Comment: I don't expect the server to fail. I don't expect to see a response with data, which is allowed just to the white list. Now I get a response with the data. It is a problem. BTW it works fine for POST, it doesn't work just for GET requests

Comment: The only reason POST is "working" is that you're throwing an Error instead of handling the request nicely...

Rejecting the request on the server side based on the Origin header is a mistake since the client can just change the Origin header value to what your server wants (http://localhost:3000) and bypass your "protection". The point is for the server to reply with information telling a browser who can access that information.

Comment: Can you please give an example how to handle it nicely? I am looking for examples. Everywhere I see this if (!origin || allowed.includes(origin)) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error(`Origin ${origin} not allowed by CORS`));
    } For example here https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-cors-in-nodejs-with-express/

Comment: What should I set in callback if the origin is not in the white list?

Comment: You can just use `callback(null, false)` instead: the examples that you see fail the call, but as explained this is not the purpose of cors in general.